# make asynctask run faster

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

i am making a chat application it is working but it is slow. i need a way to make it work faster it reads data from mysql database and displays it..... and i am using asynctask ....

```
package com.mall.our;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

import com.mall.first.JSONParser;
import com.mall.first.Login;
import com.mall.first.MainActivity;

import com.mall.first.R;


public class Chat extends SherlockListFragment {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_pic = "pic";
    public static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO = "categories_logo";


  //user details
    private static final String NAME = "name";
    private static final String AGE = "age";
    private static final String STATUS = "status";
    private static final String PIC = "pic";
    private static final String SEX = "sex"; String friendname,status;

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        //user
    private static final String URL = "http://www.thethinker.com.ng/ochat/chattingname.php";
    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://www.thethinker.com.ng/ochat/selectchat.php";

        private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
        private ListView lv;
        SharedPreferences sp ;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
     @Override 
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  

            new LoadComments().execute(); 
 }

       class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
              String username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_CATEGORY, "POST",
                            params);

                  try {

                      JSONArray categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                      for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                          String id = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_ID");
                          String name = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_NAME");
                          String pic = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_pic");
                          String message = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_MESSAGE");

                          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                          map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                          map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                          map.put(TAG_pic, pic);
                          map.put(TAG_MESSAGE,message);

                          categoryList.add(map);
                      }
                  }catch (Throwable e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  return categoryList;
              }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                mAdapter = new OtherlistAdapter(getActivity(),result);
                setListAdapter(mAdapter);
                lv = getListView();
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                        final int position, long id) {


                    class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                            pDialog.setMessage("Wait..");
                            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            pDialog.show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                                        int success;
                                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                        HashMap<String, String> name = 
                                                (HashMap<String, String>) mAdapter.getItem(position);
                                        String n=name.get(TAG_NAME);


                                        try {

                                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", n));


                                            Log.d("request!", "starting");

                                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST",
                                                    params);

                                            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                                            String sex=json.getString(SEX);
                                            String age=json.getString(AGE);
                                            String pic=json.getString(PIC);
                                            String statuss = json.getString(STATUS);

                                            // json success tag
                                            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                                            if (success == 1) {

                                                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());


                                                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                                                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                                                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                                                edit.putString("value", n);
                                                edit.putString("sex", sex);
                                                edit.putString("age", age);
                                                edit.putString("pic", pic);
                                                edit.putString("statuss", statuss);

                                                edit.commit();

                                                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),Chatting.class);


                                                startActivity(i);   

                                                       return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                                            } else {
                                                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                                                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                                        }

                                        return null;

                                    }
                        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();




                        }

                        }
                      new loginAccess().execute();  

                }

            });

            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see te second asynctask is in the postexecute of the first asynctask...it is meant to take the username of the user in to the next class  called "CHATTING.java"....... at first when is click it goes to "chatting.java" class a bit slowly........ but when i go back to chat.java class and try to go back to "chatting.java"... it just get too slow

Below is chatting.java class....

```
package com.mall.our;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.mall.first.JSONParser;
import com.mall.first.MessageCategoryList;
import com.mall.first.R;
import com.mall.our.Chat.LoadComments;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Chatting extends ListActivity {
// fr the sending of message
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_time = "time";
    public static final String TAG_state = "state";
    public static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "categories_message";
    public static final String TAG_CATEGORIES_LOGO = "categories_logo";
    public static final String TAG_from = "from ";
    //end


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final String URL_CATEGORY = "http://www.thethinker.com.ng/ochat/selectmess.php";
    private static final String url = "http://www.thethinker.com.ng/ochat/sendmessage.php";
    private static final String ur = "http://www.thethinker.com.ng/ochat/seen.php";
    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    EditText mess;
    private ListView lv;
    ImageButton send;
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    Intent b = getIntent();
    String state;
    int flag = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.yon);
        mess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mess);
        send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setDivider(null);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(Chatting.this, "Item selected: " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
         final Handler ham = new Handler();
            Runnable race = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    new LoadComments().execute();

                    ham.postDelayed(this, 1 * 1000);
                }

            };
            ham.postDelayed(race, 1 * 1000);

                ff();
        sending();
    }




    private void sending() {
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                if (!isOnline(Chatting.this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Chatting.this, "No network connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }


                new sendtext().execute();

            }


            private boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
    public void ff(){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Chatting.this);
String friendname = sp.getString("value", "anon");
String sta = sp.getString("statuss", "anon");
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
     TextView stat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    name.setText(friendname);
    stat.setText(sta);


}

        class LoadComments extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        int priorPosition=  getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Chatting.this);

            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                Void... arg0) {
               int successr;

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Chatting.this);
            String friend = sp.getString("value", "anon");
            String username = sp.getString("username", "anon");

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friend", friend));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_CATEGORY, "POST",
                    params);


            try {

                List<NameValuePair> seen = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                seen.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                seen.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friend", friend));

                successr = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                JSONArray categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                    String id = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString("TAG_ID");
                    String time = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "TAG_time");
                    String songs_count = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "TAG_CATEGORIES_COUNT");
                    String from = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "TAG_from");
                state = categories.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                            "TAG_state");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_time, time);
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, songs_count);
                    map.put(TAG_from, from);
                    map.put(TAG_state, state);


                    categoryList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return categoryList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            mAdapter = new MessageCategoryList(Chatting.this,result);
            lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            getListView().setSelection(priorPosition);



        }
    }

    class sendtext extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Chatting.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("posting...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Chatting.this);
            String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");

            String friendname = sp.getString("value", "anon");
            String picc = sp.getString("pic", "anon");
            String message = mess.getText().toString();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", post_username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to", friendname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pic", picc));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (flag == 1)
                Toast.makeText(Chatting.this, " saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            mess.setText("");
        }


      }

}
```

Comment: Why using an `AsyncTask` at all? I'd suggest you dig into Google Cloud Messaging and notify your client actively whenever a new message arrives. This is much more efficient. Check this example: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-chat-application-using-gcm-client.html

Comment: ok would i bet able to save messages in my database

Comment: Now if you first would tell us why it is slower the second time...

Answer (score 1):

Make the following optimizations:

- cache frequently used data, so you do not have to query for it from a large table
- add indexes to the fields you are searching for
- archive old, rarely used data to archive tables
- make sure your queries are optimal and you are merging whatever is possible without raising the complexity of your queries

Comment: thank you what do you mean by add indexes to the fields you are searching for

Answer (score 0):

you are trying a chat application with asynchrone connection ,  i think it's not good like idea , i advice you to use WebSocket for connection in real-time (synchrone connection), you can find a many examples which use use websocket for chat application like this : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/
- you need implement a server side 
- then your application ..
I hope you like this approach

Comment: it is for group chat not priate chat

Comment: here is a sample example for chat non-group ; you need a little knowing for a ruby language : https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example